# Simplest and easiest way to convert dd/mm/yy to date in php

Tags: php, date, date-format, strtotime

I am yet to find a simple way to do this and very few places address date formats with 2 years. I have read `strtotime()` and it really only handles 4 digit years or American format - which doesn't help me.

In the end, I generally end up breaking the string into an array, adding 20 in front of year and converting with that BUT that just seems really cumbersome.

I toiled with this example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#100144 and couldn't get it to work... It seemed so simple... then I read the notes;

`Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.`

Is there a more economical way of processing these dates or will I forever be forced to perform 3-4 lines of conversion every time?

RO Date: 19/04/18
RO Date: 18/06/18
RO Date: 19/06/18
RO Date: 19/06/18
RO Date: 19/06/18

Comment: Use a custom date format, explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: Give an example date

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: `24/12/18` (this year, Christmas Eve), described in the title of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Simplest and easiest way to convert dd/mm/yy to date in php?

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
<?php
$date = '24/03/83';
//
echo date_create_from_format('d/m/y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or

```
<?php
$date = '24/03/83';
//
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Result:**

```
1983-03-24
```

https://3v4l.org/KIVbM

Use `Y` if year is `1983`, see manual link above for all formats.

Comment: or the OP wants to get, like: `19/04/18 => d/m/y`, and the added benefit is that not only the OP can format dates, but also get to incorporate date addition / subtractions and intervals and date periods and such, plus, no more string manipulations, like what the OP does in the current code setup, (just adding more info)

Comment: Thanks, That will work - I just want to get a date in any format to use to compare against now() to get the date difference.